# Opposite of individualism?

Tags: ethics, psychology, psychoanalysis

If a person was not an individualist, What action would he or she take, in response to setting someone getting hurt, or killed?

Comment: How do you define the word individualist in your question?

Comment: "Opposite of individualism?" [Altruism or selflessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altruism).

Comment: The question as it stands cannot be answered, philosophical positions such as individualism define what ought to motivate ones actions, you are asking for the resultant action. For all consequntialist ethics this would depend on the agent's knowledge of total outcomes which you have not specified.

Answer (score 0):

In some sense, if you hold no trace of individualism, it should not matter that one is seeing someone victimized, as long as you know certainly that people are, everywhere, being victimized.  So no particular reaction is actually required.

Of course, if you are not defensively individualistic, compassion toward the victim and reconsideration of the value of the perpetrator is just going to happen, that is almost a biological fact.  It can be resisted only by choosing to fight it, which seems perverse.  So, if you can comfort the victim or their family, or if you can reasonably and meaningfully take the victimizer to task in the moment, you should follow the natural call to do so.

Effectiveness should be considered over personal risk, because your individual value is lower, in toto, than that of the many future people this particular perpetrator might victimize.  You need to consider the human ability to completely change, but also its limited likelihood.  So what an individualist would label 'heroics' even to the point of para-suicidal intervention, that risks your own life for that of the victim, or some future victim, are not out of order.  (It is in this spirit that some monks from anti-individualistic sects are trained in the proper deployment of violence.  Stepping into situations of misapplied violence is a natural reaction, if you can effectively restore balance, and serve the greater good.)

But your reaction to an event does not need to differ because of your involvement.  In a truly selfless world, your experience is not special, and your responsibilities are not prescribed to you individually.

So how does one react to the overall existence of victimization?  That clearly depends upon the kind of victimization, but the overall approach would have to be to look at the global effect of attempting to control the dynamic causing the victimization.  For instance, if this is a hate crime, what is the positive impact of tribalism?  Is that worth the loss, and can it be accomplished efficiently in other ways?  If this is a simple crime of passion, what can we do to appropriately reinforce responsibility, across the board, unrelated to any given case?

To my mind, you are led to a more naturalistic framing of Kantian ethics, where one must respect autonomy, but can presume a layer of shared human instincts that inform the preferences of individuals.  Act in the way you could generalize, given the shared notion of human nature that replaces individualism as the root of autonomy.